# I-20 name in opposite order

Tags: indian-citizens

I have got my I-20 form where the Surname is : Subham and given name is: Saha. But my passport has surname: Saha and given name: Subham. My passport name is correct. I am an Indian. What should I do?

Comment: Which one is correct?

Comment: @bytebuster We can't say it's a duplicate without knowing whether it's the I-20 or the passport that is wrong. The other question is about a passport that was mistakenly issued with the names switched. In that case, the answer is clearly to get the passport fixed. But if the passport here is correct, that obviously doesn't apply.

Comment: Passport is correct.

Comment: Contact the school's international office immediately.

Comment: Does name in I-20 has to match with passport?

Comment: This question needs more context.  I-20 form for what?  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

As the comment says, contact the university's international student office or admission office that issued the I-20.  If it was their mistake, they should expedite correcting it. It's best to have a correct I-20 before your visa interview.